# WebViewJavascriptBridge on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, swift, uiwebview

So I'm creating an app in which there's a UIWebView which shows a list of locations. My goal is to make it possible that once the user clicks one of the locations, my app can get the lat and longitude of the spot and therefore launch an integrated Navigation SDK.
My point is how do I get and pass the location values from the webView to my Objective-C code?
I'm using WebViewJavascriptBridge.

Comment: How did you load the html and javascript ? handling in `WebViewJavascriptBridge ` I am actually seeing a loader keep on loading in `WKWebView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the hyperlinks on the locations.

For example: `<a href="location1,latitude=21,longitude=22" id="location1" >Location1</a>`

Once this `Location1` gets clicked, `- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method will be called, and you can extract value of latitude and longitude

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ask for the web developer to have try at this later, I'll inform you how it works.

Comment: It actually worked well! Thanks a lot! Plus I came across with a problem that once we click on the hyperlinks the WebView would go to another page, but I managed to fix that using a method of WebView.

Answer (score 0):

`WebViewJavascriptBridge`  have no maintain for a long time.

Maybe you should change to use this library.

[SDBridgeOC](https://github.com/SDBridge/SDBridgeOC)

```
 self.bridge.consolePipeBlock = ^(id  _Nonnull water) {
        NSLog(@"Next line is javascript console.log------>>>>");
        NSLog(@"%@",water);
    };
```

This can easy to get javascript console.log.

Also have Swift language Version.

[SDBridgeSwift](https://github.com/SDBridge/SDBridgeSwift)

```
bridge.consolePipeClosure = { water in
         guard let jsConsoleLog = water else {
             print("Javascript console.log give native is nil!")
              return
         }
         print("Next line is Javascript console.log----->>>>>>>")
         print(jsConsoleLog)
      }
```

Also have h5 demo for you.